# Trying to get property of non-object - Undefined variable: data/ Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i'm try to get news_id from database but when go to view say : error -> Trying to get property of non-object / Message: Undefined variable: data

this model - >

```
class Model1 extends CI_Model {
  public function get_art()
  {
    $query = $this->db->get('entries');
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

here controller Code - >

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
  public function members()
  {
    $this->load->model('model1');
    $data=$this->model1->get_art();
    $this->load->view('members', $data);
  }
}
```

and this Full View - >

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
<? echo $data->body; ?>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of you invalid pass data to view. At controller replace line

```
$data=$this->model1->get_art();
```

with

```
$data["query"] = $this->model1->get_art();
```

Then at view you will have var $query with results of your database query.

You can use it like this:

```
<h1>
<? foreach($query as $row) {
    echo $row->body;
} 
?>
</h1>
```